# how to install downloaded wordpress theme in xampp

Tags: css, wordpress, installation, xampp, wordpress-theming

I am trying to install a theme I downloaded from [this website](http://themeforest.net).
I am using XAMPP and I am not sure how to install this dowloaded theme using XAMPP.
I tried installing this theme with the zip folder (in zip format) in Wordpress but I get the error
” The package could not be installed. The theme is missing the style.css stylesheet.
Theme install failed. “

I [found a similar](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/the-theme-is-missing-the-stylecss-stylesheet) on Wordpress website but they mentioned using FTP but I don’t know how to use FTP with XAMPP

I want to install the theme and test it out locally before I make it live or buy a domain name.

This is my first time doing this (I am a student) so I don’t totally know how things work together, don’t know if I am using the description/terms but I hope I described the problem well enough.

How to go about this? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

OK so its a bit weird that the theme you downloaded is missing the CSS file. When you upload it Wordpress is trying to find that file and failing. For now, let's assume that the creator of the theme put the CSS file in a different location than usual.

To install a theme manually via XAMPP do the following:

1. Locate XAMPP's htdocs folder. This is normally Applications>>XAMPP>>HTDOCs on Mac or My Computer>>C:>>XAMPP>>HTDOCs on Windows (I think - someone might need to correct me on that).
2. If your site is installed in a sud-directory in htdocs, go there. If not skip to next step.
3. Open the wp-content folder
4. Open the themes folder
5. Copy in your downloaded theme and extract it there (if its zipped)
6. Go to your Wordpress Dashboard and go to the Appearance button on the left and click Themes from the drop down. Find your newly installed theme and hit Activate.

That should do the trick unless your theme is missing some vital elements

(PS: what your are doing here - moving (theme) files from one location to another - is essentially the same as FTP. Difference is FTP allows you to transfer files accross the internet from computer to computer: say your computer to a web server hosting your site.)

Answer (score 1):

Add this lines to your wp-config.php file

```
//** To add the direct installation of the themes **//
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Then go to wp-admin and click on customize your site. Press on change button on the active theme and browse for your favorite theme from wordpress.org and install then enjoy

Comment: I think this is the correct solution

Comment: this will help too 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046977/xampp-permissions-on-mac-os-x