# Mac OS loading XAMPP prompts password

Tags: osx-lion, xampp

I am using Lion 10.8.2, and in sudoers i made like this: username  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD, the username is my computer user... but still now prompts password.. What to do ?

Comment: where is it prompting for a password?  Your Terminal shell or in the browser or while installing or somewhere else?

Comment: its prompt when I want to load xampp to turn on Apache and MySQL.

Comment: This sounds like a permissions problem.  I wish I could enter this in as my own "answer", but [check the solutions to this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046977/xampp-permissions-on-mac-os-x) and see if this helps you.

Comment: In your mentioned link, where are only write & read permissions. My problem with sudo which always promt password...

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the Pop Up window while starting the servers then you cannot get away with it. An API(Don't know which exactly) is used to start the Apache server which requires administrator privileges. sudo in the terminal and this API call is different, editing any files won't help.

Port 80, default port of Apache is a [Well-Known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports) port which requires admin privileges as written in the link. So they must have forcefully added the API Call for starting the server.