# NetBeans 7.3.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.5 can't find source folders (open project with existing source)

Tags: php, macos, netbeans

I am getting started with NetBeans PHP package on a Mac OS X 10.7.5 
and when I try to open a project with `PHP Application with existing source` then click `Browse` for the source folder, it shows nothing inside `Application` folder.

The source folder is in `Application/MAMP/htdocs/` but I don't know why it doesn't show up in NetBeans.

Has anyone ever experienced this before?

Comment: Does NetBeans have permissions to read/write files in /Application/MAMP/htdocs?

Comment: @ladar Hi, thanks for the comment. How do I know whether NetBeans have permissions or not? Where can I access this info?

Comment: You can check permissions from terminal 

   cd /Application/MAMP/htdocs
   ls -la

(see similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046977/xampp-permissions-on-mac-os-x) or faster could be to try to create a new PHP project inside the htdocs from NetBeans, create some PHP files, close these files in NetBeans and open them again.

Comment: @ladar Thank you, this helped me. You should submit this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this issue trying to set up Netbeans on OSX for the first time. NB could not see the contents of /Applications (which is where AMPPS keeps /www), and changing permissions did not work for me.

Simpler solution was to create a symlink in Terminal:

```
ln -s /Applications/AMPPS/www /Users/Username/Documents/www
```

Netbeans can now see this folder