# CodeIgniter on XAMPP - 403/404 Error accessing images

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, xampp

I'm literally struggling to understand why, as it seems, I can't load any image to my local Codeigniter installation on XAMPP.

I have placed an `img` folder into the `application` folder, containing only an image named `arrow.png` but I cannot access it nor show it on my views.

I have the suspect this might be a **.htaccess** problem but I have tried different solutions with no success. This is what I have at the moment:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|assets|cache|themes|uploads)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In my config PHP I've edited of course:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

In my view called `ordine.php` I called my image like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url("img/arrow.png"); ?>" title="Go to Top" alt="Go to Top"/>
```

The generated URL seems right but the image doesn't shows. If I go directly on that link, I get a 404 error.

```
http://localhost/clientname/img/arrow.png
```

EDIT:
Could it be something with my httpd.conf apache file, set up as the following?

```
Alias /bitnami/ "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions and help about this.

Comment: did you try setting the base_url in config?

Comment: At the moment it is set up as my local IP (so other users in the same network can see it from other computers without problems), but even changing it back to localhost seems not working.

Comment: if localhost is working, then within config set base_url to `http://<computername>.<domainname>.com/clientname/` and check if that works

Comment: No it is not, I wrote wrong and modified right a second after my answer :P

Comment: Here you go with my row in config.php: $config['base_url'] = http://MYLOCALIP/clientname/';

Comment: can you change the local ip to the hostname?

Comment: Just tried, but nothing changes. I don't think my problem resides in base_url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed the problem myself, after an hard search. It all turned out to be OS X permissions not allowing me to see the images in particolar subfolders. What I had to do is written on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046977/xampp-permissions-on-mac-os-x).

Thank you to anyone who put efforts to try to help me out - with this kind of problems, is always quite hard to understand if its a local OS problem or webserver problem.

Comment: Great! All the best and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Check your htaccess file.Whether it has allowed images to load in the webpage.Here i'll put a working htaccess file.Try it..

```
RewriteBase /clientname/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

You could also refer to a forum [here](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/131236/#647804) that has a discussion on CI not able to display images

Comment: you probably want to replace images with img

Comment: @hades2510, yes you are right. made the changes. Thanks!

Comment: Nothing to do. Tried to change my htaccess file like yours and nothing changes. By the way, I'm speaking about the htaccess located in the root of Codeigniter, the one inside the /application folder just contains "Deny from all"

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately. However now im getting a 404 Error page from Codeigniter, not the normal one from the webserver

Comment: what is the relative path for the image

Comment: Well the image is placed in xampp/htdocs/clientname/application/img/ so it should be just /img/ I guess

Comment: and does this url `http://localhost/clientname/img/arrow.png` in browser render correctly?

Comment: Nope. I get 404 Page Not Found.

Comment: can you try `http://localhost/clientname/application/img/arrow.png` and post if that worked

Comment: This time I get a 403 error from the webserver - as it found the file, but I cannot access it I think

Comment: did you edit anything in the index.php file in the root directory?

Comment: can you move the img folder out of the application directory and to the root directory and try to access it with url `http://localhost/clientname/img/arrow.png`

Comment: remove any .htaccess files that are available in img folder and see if you are accessing the right url. Just to confirm and have a double check

Comment: You know what? I removed the .htaccess (containing the code you gave me) and I keep getting the 403 error....

Comment: you do not have to remove the .htaccess from the root folder. You have to check if any .htaccess is available in img folder that we copied to the root directory and if available, remove the .htaccess only from img folder

Comment: Oh, ok. No, anyways, no .htaccess files in the img folder. Just the arrow.png itself

Comment: and can you confirm you have 

 1. img folder having arrow.png in the root directory
 2. Calling the url http://localhost/clientname/img/arrow.png

Comment: Yes I confirm both 100%. Could it be maybe something with my apace httpd.conf file? I edited the main post

Comment: is the folder name `img` or `Img`? since unix is case sensitive

Comment: can you add `RewriteBase /clientname/` within your .htaccess as i edited in my answer and try

Comment: Also added a link [Not Able to Display Images](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/131236) which might help

Comment: Nothing different happening, I'm starting to think to reinstall Codeigniter into a different folder or something else - since im going totally desperate

Comment: can you check the link i have posted

Comment: Also, [this](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/131236/#652268) solution looks promising

Comment: Just checked it but its not my case

Comment: Mine is not a problem of links, mine is a problem that I cant access images not even by inserting their URL directly in the browser

Comment: I fixed it, read my answer. Thanks a lot for your help - it helped me to focalize the problem and understand it was not CI config's related.

Answer (score 0):

```
         <?php echo base_url("/img/arrow.png"); ?>
```

Try this.

Comment: Doesn't do the trick, the URL generated is just the same: http://localhost/clientname/img/arrow.png and it should be correct but I still get the damn 404 error. "The page you requested was not found."

Comment: I have tried and it doesn't. I can't even access directly the file from my browser! @user983983

Comment: please read the question carefully before answering, op already say that "I have placed an img folder into the application folder" your answer will output relative to index.php