# How to get images to display on website while using XAMPP on Macbook Pro

Tags: php, html, css, xampp

I built an HTML/CSS website and then added PHP functionality. Installed XAMPP. Since installing XAMPP, everything on the site works except the images. Image files don't display. They are all properly referencing the directory. In fact, before using XAMPP, the images displayed fine on the HTML webpages. After using XAMPP and re-saving as .php, they stopped working. Nothing else changed. I figure it must be a settings issue. Thoughts, anybody?

Thanks a billion in advance!

Comment: Check the path of images from console..it must be wrong..

Comment: NOTE: when I go directly to http://localhost/LawFinder/Images/fake9-mini.jpg in my browser, I get an "ACCESS FORBIDDEN!" error 403 page.

Answer (score 2):

@john steve I had also the same issue. I tried lots of thing suggested on different forums but it did not work. Finally I set up permission for each images and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. And the reason was that my `images` folder had `no-access` permission. I changed the permission to Read/Write for admin and Read-only for everyone else. It is possible to change permission for each individual time but it is time consuming, therefore changing the permission of parent folder is effective.

**The following steps are for MAC OS:**

- Open applications folder
- Locate XAMPP folder
- Right click > get info.
- In pop-up window locate the 'sharing & permission' section
- Click the 'locked' padlock symbol
- Enter admin password
- Change 'Everyone' permissions to read & write
- In the get info window still, select the 'cog' icon' drop down option
  at the very bottom and select 'Apply to enclosed items' this will
  adjust the permission across all sub-folders as well.
- Re-lock the padlock symbol
- Close the 'Get Info' window.

**And for Windows:**
 -

- Locate XAMPP folder
- Right-click the folder, click Properties, and then click the Security tab.
- Click Edit to open the Permissions for <Object> dialog box.
- Click the name of the group or user.
- In the Permissions for <User or Group> box, select the Allow check box.

***References:*** [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc754344.aspx) and [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046977/xampp-permissions-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

Its probably an issue with accessing local files on a "domain" that is not local. Just update you're images path to something relative or within localhost and it will be fine. Its a browser security thingy to not load local files when you are not opening a file directly from a file path. (Cross-domain or Same-origin policy). The idea is to not let any website sniff your local files and it doesn't work differently for localhost which can be an alias to any IP (doesn't nnecessarily to be 'local').

To fix this issue, move all your assets into the folder that is the root for localhost and e.g. use "images/someImage.jpg" instead of "c:\somePath\someImage.jpg". You cannot mix up c:\ with a page served from `http://localhost/.`

You will see this issue popping up in the network panel of chrome developer tools or Firebug extension when working with Firefox. It's really NOT recommended to, but it's possible to turn off this crucial security settings: http://joshuamcginnis.com/2011/02/28/how-to-disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome/ - I would warn anybody to do it that way, though.

Comment: Right now the paths are relative: background-image: url('../Images/imageName.jpg'). Should it differ from that?

Comment: NOTE also: when I go directly to localhost/LawFinder/Images/fake9-mini.jpg in my browser, I get an "ACCESS FORBIDDEN!" error 403 page.

Comment: where is your index.html located? Also, if your /images/ folder (notice small/capital letters are important here!) is right inside the folder set to be the root, you don't need the LawFinder in front of it.

Comment: My index is in applications/xampp/htdocs. I had a relative url originally: Images/imageName.jpg. But that didn't work. So i tried it with the /LawFinder/ and it still doesn't work. I'm pretty lost...What was your point about the lowercase i? Should it be lowercase? My folder is uppercase, and uppercase worked before using php and putting it into htdocs.

Comment: Nono, its fine if your folder is named like that. My point was, that it matters. I've seen that u fixed it - no need to follow this thread anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

@Manuel is right. If the problem persists, try absolute paths in image `src`. The absolute paths will be like `http://localhost:8888/your-website-folder/your-images-folder/your-image-name`
In windows you don't use port number (which is 8888) in this case

Good luck.

Comment: I just tried:  background-image: url('localhost:8888/website/Images/imageName.jpg');

Didn't work... :/

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem: all of my images had permissions marked: "everyone: no access." I changed it to: "everyone: read only" I did this simply by right clicking (aka control-clicking) each image and then clicking "get info." I then scrolled down to "Sharing & Permissions." It's self explanatory from there. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set read and write permissions to each image you want to use.  I assume you can probably do the entire folder in and it will cascade down.  On mac right click (two finger) => get info => at bottom set all to read/write.  reload page. Presto.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the folder name. Don't use uppercase letter in folder names. I tried all solutions advices but finally found that solution. My pictures folder was "Resimler" then I couldn't see the pictures but I changed as "resimler" then it is worked.