# XAMPP permission issue on MacOSx

Tags: php, macos, xampp

I have an issue with my XAMPP installation on MacOSx Yosemite.

I have looked at a couple of threads, specifically this one [XAMPP permissions on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046977/xampp-permissions-on-mac-os-x)

I have tried the solutions there but i havent gotten any of them to work.

I am running a website on it that reads, and creates files in php. I need to authorize access to the htdocs folder by right clicking it going into info, and them unlocking the padlock. Only then can I write files. This is very annoying, and not ideal for working on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Xammp use a different user like www-data, you can change owner of the directory in recursive mode with chown.

```
sudo chown xampp-user /path/to/directory -R
```

And you may need to change chmod for that directories.

```
sudo chmod 755 /path/to/directory -R
```

But when you copy or move a directory from another place to xampp path, you'll need to do these steps again cause owner will be different. And i agree this is not a ideal environment.

Personally it will be easier using [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) for development. To put it simply, it's a headless virtualbox. This way you won't have a problem about permissions or something like that. If you did not use vagrant before [puphpet](https://puphpet.com/) is a good place to create a local environment.

Comment: ok. I will definetively take a look at vagrant, and puphet (not sure if you ment puPHPet) as a solution. otherwise i will take a look at number one!

Comment: Thanks. I got some ideas based upon your solution. What i ended up doing was i set up a linux apache2 server, installed some libraries, an ftp server and a few other things. I just ftp files in there when i need to. I could not seem to get puPHPet to work properly, it basically shat itself all the time, so i set up my own server using linux ubuntu. the sudo chown command worked as well, but it was just extremely tedious to use all the time, as my php code makes new folders and such all the time! Thanks for your help!