# Application folder not showing XAMPP or any subfolder in Netbeans

Tags: php, macos, netbeans, netbeans-8

I want to create a PHP project using existing source in Netbeans. But when I try to give path of my existing project inside `Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/ProjectFolder`, the Applications folder doesn't showing any subfolders. I have attached image of this.

[image]

As you can see there is no subfolder inside Applications folder. All other Folders for eg. Desktop, Documents showing its subfolders.

I am using netbeans version 8.0.2 and Mac OS 10.10.2

My Applications and XAMPP folders permission is as follows

[image]

I have tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12656964/1679187) solution but no help.

What I need to change the configuration to get the subfolders of Applications?

Comment: Try to check your permission in your xampp folder... May be cause of that ..

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam XAMPP is also having same permission as Applications folder.

Comment: is there any folder named `nbproject` in your application folder ?

Comment: In Applications folder all installed apps are present. How can there be any `nbproject` in that. This folder is present in netbeans project folder, but in my scenario it is not present because I have created manually not using Netbeans.

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam I have followed same process, but in third step when I try to locate the existing folder(which is inside Applications\XAMPP\htdocs) but Applications folder not showing the inner subfolder, see attached screenshot. Hoping that you understand the question.

Comment: so the problem occur when you locate your existing folder but not showing up inner subfolder right ?

Comment: I'am afraid that still a bug, from earlier `netbeans 7`...
Did you try to create a new PHP project using project wizard and after that you just copied the `htdocs/project folder` in it ?

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam Yes that's the problem. No I haven't tried that way.

Comment: you can try it that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking in wrong `Applications` folder where XAMPP is installed. But actually all apps are installing inside root's Application folder.

[image]

After going in root's folder Applications folder showing all inner subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out :

Importing Existing Local Source Files into a Project

1. In the Projects area, choose PHP Application with Existing Sources
   and click Next. The New PHP Project > Name and Location panel opens.
2. In the Project Name text field, enter the name of the project.
3. In the Sources Folder field, specify the folder from where you want
   to import the source files.
   Note: If you are going to run the [project on a local web server](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/project-setup.html#localServer), do not forget to specify [copying the source files](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/project-setup.html#copyFilesFromSourcesFolder) to it.
4. From the Default Encoding dropdown list, choose the default encoding
   for your project.
5. If you want to store NetBeans metadata in a different location than
   your source files, select "Put NetBeans metadata into a separate
   directory." For example, you might want to store your sources in
   your document root but the NetBeans metadata in your
   NetBeansProjects directory.
6. Click Next. The Run Configuration panel opens.

For detail information please read [this](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/project-setup.html).