# fopen not working (directory not recognised)

Tags: php, directory, fopen

The user selects a button. Through the method post, and an if statement, some PHP is executed. The code to illustrate this is as follows:

```html
<?php

  function onClickArchive(){

    $relative_path = "load_more/newfile.php";
  $myfile = fopen($relative_path, "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
  $txt = "testing\n";
  fwrite($myfile, $txt);
  $txt = "testing\n";
  fwrite($myfile, $txt);
  fclose($myfile);

 }

if(isset($_POST['load_more'])){
 
      onClickArchive();
      
    }
?>


  
  
<div id="reload_section">
<center><br />
 <form  method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Load More" name="load_more" class="load_more_content" />
 </form>
</center>
</div>
```

When the user select the button and the PHP is executed, the following error occurs:

[image]

I think that the PHP cannot find the "load_more" directory - is this the case? And if so, is there any way I can fix it?

My Directory looks like the following illustration:

```html
-----------------------------
load_more(folder)
  newfile.php
-----------------------------
archive_general.php
-----------------------------
archive(folder)
  archive_main_body.php
-----------------------------
```

The page that the PHP ***fopen*** code is implemented onto is the ***archive_main_body.php***.

However, the ***archive_main_body.php*** page has been included in the ***archive_general.php*** page - which is the page that the error occurs on.

Comment: check folder/file permissions. Anything from error reporting if not already doing so? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred -ii-, How do I do this? Thanks

Comment: you on windows or a NIX system?

Comment: Im using apache, installed on Mac OS X

Comment: See this Q&A on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046977/xampp-permissions-on-mac-os-x

Comment: it worked, cheers @Fred -ii-

Comment: Glad to hear it,*cheers*

Comment: I take it that it was folder/file permissions?

Comment: You're welcome. So, what would you like to do with the question? Delete it? My marking it as a duplicate with the link I gave you earlier? Post an answer? The choice is yours. ;-)

Comment: Cheers for the choice @Fred -ii-, probably best for the community if it was marked as a duplicate because I think it probably is? What do you think?

Comment: Marked as a duplicate, *no harm done* ;-)