# Trying to run Duplicator (Wordpress plugin) to install a copy of a site on XAMPP

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

I'm trying to install a copy of a wordpress site on my localhost. I'm using Xampp. It is not working it is saying that : The deployment path must be writable by PHP in order to extract the archive file.

I don't know what to do to fix it, I'm on mac, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the folder permissions before you can use PHP to extract a zip file. Open the folder properties (CMD-ALT-I or whatever it is)

See [XAMPP permissions on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046977/xampp-permissions-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer. It works perfectly

Comment: You're welcome. It's the same on most hosting servers by the way, as OSX is unix based, and most hosting servers run on linux.

Comment: But on php now I have this message : PhpMyAdmin “Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable!”

Comment: Be careful! Only change the permission to the htdocs, because if you change all permission mysql won't work