# Couldn't create directory error in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I installed a XAMPP application and used localhost to install the latest version of WordPress. Every time I try to upload the or update plugin or theme, it gives me an error

> Couldn't create the directory.

I'm using Mac OS X, I've changed the permissions as well as I have added the `define('FS_METHOD','direct');` command in the wp-config file. However, it is still not working for me.

What can I do in this case?

**UPDATE**

I have already tried following the steps in this article:

[XAMPP permissions on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046977/xampp-permissions-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: try the answer for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046977/xampp-permissions-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Hi, please do not get defensive. If you have tried something include it in your post. Also, you may want to look at formatting your question better to help attract people to want to answer it for you. Check out this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for this mate. I’m new here, hopefully soon I will be familiar with all policies & rules.