# Permission denied when saving a file to xampp htdocs directory

Tags: php, mysql, htdocs

Hello I have this problem that I am trying to save a file to a directory on htdocs it says permission denied.

```
  <?php


$image = file_get_contents('http://www.affiliatewindow.com/logos/1961/logo.gif');
file_put_contents('./images/myFile.gif', $image);
```

[image]

Comment: Forgive me but what part of that error isn't clear? Your web server user does not have the authority to write to that directory.

Comment: what is your os?

Comment: I am only using localhost or my own ser and i am saving the file from the internet to my folder on htdocs.

how to grant the permission.

Comment: mac os high siera

Comment: maybe you don't have permission.

Comment: how to add permission

Comment: there is a solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12656964/1144627)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to allow the permission to insert the image into the specific folder which is in htdocs 
for an example
In ubuntu

```
sudo chmod 644 /opt/lampp/hdocs/yourfolder
```

like wise you have to give permission to access that specific folder

Comment: @Jan Genvher Papica is this help full to you?

Comment: Tried `sudo chmod 755 /path` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Also i tried to change the owner to `www-data` but failed to solve the problem.

Comment: Please explain further

Comment: I solved it by changing the owners permissions of the directory.
Through `Properties` dialog box , i changed both `owner` and `group` to `www-data` , and gave them access to `Create and delete files` , also i gave `others` the same level of access.
I know this might be a very bad idea , but that's the only solution that seems to be working for me.

Comment: Yeah worked for me by changing `owner` and `group` to my `laptpop_userName`