# Why wordpress can't write files using php with xampp in localserver

Tags: php, xampp

I am using xampp from longtime without have this problem in my localhost. But suddenly all of my Wordpress product can't write file. It give error don't have access permission.

Also when I try to install new Wordpress it give me "Unable to write to wp-config.php file"

How can I give xampp or PHP give full access of xampp document folder ("htdocs" I has change it default htdocs folder)?

Answer (score 1):

This will add required permission to wordpress directory:

`sudo chown -R daemon:daemon /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/wordpress`

Enter your system password and done!

please change the path of directory if its different.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give permission to your localhost.

This answer should solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51565645/4781377