# PHP unable to create a directory with mkdir

Tags: php, apache, permissions, mkdir, selinux

I have a previously working PHP script that is able to create a directory with `mkdir`:

```
$webfolder = "/var/www/html/images/user";
mkdir($webfolder, 0770);
```

I made some changes to the permission setting of the folder `/var/www/html/images` which is now:

```
drwxrwx---. myself apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 images
```

I think previously this folder was owned by `apache`. But since `apache` has the full privileges of read, write and execute as a user group, I wonder why it can't create a folder within. Using the `mkdir` produces a `false` boolean value.

Is the problem due to directory ownership or is there some other reasons? Note that I am using PHP version 5.4.

**Error Log added:**

> [Mon Dec 17 11:12:34 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning: 
>   mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/html/upload on line 33,
>   referer: https://mywebsite.com/referer

Comment: Does the folder `/var/www/html/images/user` exists? If yes, with which permissions? And can you - for testing purporses - change the owner of the parent folder to `apache` and try if it works then?

Comment: @hakre, it is SELinux that is giving me problem. See my answer. Thanks for your patience and time :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The answer is staring right in front of me, but I miss it due to my unfamiliarity with SELinux.

The SELinux context type should be set as `httpd_sys_content_rw_t` instead of `httpd_sys_content_t` so that the folder is both readable and writable for apache. Changing the context recursively is done with the following command:

```
# chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t /var/www/html/images
```

Good grief. Hope it helps others who come across this.

Comment: Hi 'm having the same problem here.. with a project I'm trying to create in CodeIgnter and developing in Ubuntu 14.14 Lts.. Could you please explain to me more thoughly the steps I need to do in order to fix this error ??? To give you some additional info: the absolute path is `/opt/lampp/htdocs/www/my-app/public/uploads` .. Basically what I'm trying to do is every logged in user to upload files inside the uploads folder and also create album-folders (this will be done with php) to store photos..

Comment: You can view the topics I have created for additional information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32861261/codeigniter-message-mkdir-permission-denied-on-ubuntu, http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-63136.html, http://askubuntu.com/questions/679844/mkdir-permission-denied-to-create-folders-with-php

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS7 VM, with PHP5.4.16/Apache 2.4.6/mariadb 5.5.44, the smarty template directory was not writable to generate compiled templates files and was giving the below error (in /var/log/httpd/error_log):

```
[Thu Mar 31 12:36:08.201383 2016] [:error] [pid 13094] [client 192.168.212.65:52204] PHP Fatal error:  Smarty error: unable to write to $compile_dir '/var/www/html/app1/templates_c'. Be sure $compile_dir is writable by the web server user. in /var/www/html/app1/libs/smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1093
```

hence the PHP application was displaying blank screen.

**chmod 777 templates_c** did not work either; but as per the suggestion by @Question Overflow, permission on web root on this VM did solve the problem.

I had to execute:

```
[root@appserver html]# chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t /var/www/html
```

of course, the templates_c & cache should be owned by apache user:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  2 apache apache     6 Mar 31 12:56 templates_c
drwxr-xr-x.  2 apache apache     6 Mar 31 12:56 cache
```

After spending more than half a day, came across this.
Thanks