# Php fails to create directory while all permissions should be set:

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, permissions

I've read all the relevant topics and went trough the anwers,
but my program is still not workint properly.

I get the following error message:

```
Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/printing/uploader_temp.php on line 28
```

Where line 28 looks like this:

```
mkdir("upload", 0777, true);
```

The current user who is logged in is called "server".
The owner of both var/www/ and var/www/printing is "server". (without " of course)
The attribute of var/www/ptinting is -777.

I modified the following rows in /etc/apache2/envvars to look like this:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=server
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=server
```

and restarted apache server.

I can create folders manually on server or using FTP.

Does anyone have an idea what I did wrong?
Where else should I set permissions?

The OS is Ubuntu.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246114/php-mkdir-permission-denied-problem This could help.

Comment: Thanks, I've already read that. I am using Ubuntu, not MAC OS and I set user and group as enviroment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to give permissions to apache user? I had this problem on my web application and I solved it in two commands:

1. chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/webserver/www
2. chmod -R g+rw /path/to/webserver/www

Hope this helps for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a look to **AppArmor**:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor

Try to create a file or a directory in the `/tmp/`, can you?