# PHP: mkdir() permission denied

Tags: php, permissions, mkdir

I know there are a lot of topics about this 'problem', and I tried every solution proposed here: [PHP mkdir: Permission denied problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246114/php-mkdir-permission-denied-problem) But I still get the permission denied when I'm trying to make a folder using a PHP script.

http://i.prntscr.com/b5f37f0ff84f471bb62f250369c41625.png

For testing i've put everything under 777. albums is the one where I have to make sub dirs. In this case it's 755, but it also doesn't work with 777.

Really don't know what I can do next since I've been looking on google en SO for a few hours but still haven't got anything working.

My code to create the dir is as follows:

```
$target_path = DEFAULT_UPLOAD_PATH . $albumId . '/';
//    albums/{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}/


if (!is_dir($target_path)) {
  mkdir($target_path, 0755, true);
  print_r(error_get_last());
}
```

Comment: change chmod to 777 `mkdir($target_path, 0777, true);`

Comment: tried that, still 'permission denied'

Comment: try to change the albums folder permission to 777

Comment: 770 means the 'other' group can't write to that folder. You have to execute the script as a user or change the permissions of 'albums' as @BQKhánh said.

Comment: I've changed the album permissions to 777, but still getting the 'permission denied' error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with permissions, but with the location of the target path. It was a relative path, but I converted it to an absolute path with the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] variable.