# How to chmod 0007 a lot of directories with php?

Tags: php, apache, chmod

My Website will contain thousands of subdirectories named 'e' which are to hold user created .json files specific to that directory's submission form. I need this newly created directory to be chmod 0007. How can I do this?

This code below comes from a php file the global store function for local storage in folder 'e' but it only works right now if that folder is already there and already chmod 0007:

```
public function store(Document $document) {
    if (!isset($document->id)) { $document->id = $this->generateId(); }

        //This is my guess how to do it..
        $this->path      = $this->path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        if (!file_exists($this->path)) {
            mkdir($this->path);
            chmod($this->path, 0007);
        }
    //My guess does not work

    $path    = $this->getPathForDocument($document->id);
    $data    = $this->formatter->encode((array) $document);

    return file_put_contents($path, $data);
}
```

Note: I have searched other stack articles related to chmod via PHP, all are file related, not a directory, and/or none to date have been clear enough to help me. Please only link to something that specifically answers this exact question.

Note: This is not a question of which chmod is best. Thank you for your chmod #### concerns, I will consider those later. Please focus on an answer to the question, not one detail that bothers you, without answering.

Comment: `0007`? Are you sure about that? Can you explain why `0007`?

Comment: Perhaps he's getting confused with Bond parameters ... \*badum tssssss\*

Comment: Do note that the 2nd parameter of [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) holds the file permissions of that directory

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(['./users','./mp3','./pdf'] as $path){
    array_map(function ($val){
        return shell_exec ("chmod 0777 $val");
    }, glob("$path/*"));
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain or procide the completed solution as to how this might be used in the above posted code to modify the chmod of the directory as it creates it.

Comment: help please.....

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled on this: PHP mkdir: [PHP mkdir: Permission denied problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246114/php-mkdir-permission-denied-problem)

They suggested this: chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/example.com/public_html/ chmod -R g+rw /var/www/example.com/public_html/

It actually worked.

Thanks :)