# What is wrong with chmod 0007

Tags: php, apache, permissions, chmod

I have a php form that functions nicely with chmod 0007 despite the audible gasps coming from stackoverflow's direction. [How to chmod 0007 a lot of directories with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51667641/how-to-chmod-0007-a-lot-of-directories-with-php)

Isn't the least permission the best?

What is wrong with 0007?

What permission would you suggest for a form that writes using js/php scripts to .json files that are read and written from a pretty standard html page?

Comment: `0007` is not a PHP or apache setting/configuration. I'd start at this thread https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver.

Comment: why are you referencing your own previous post? That seems to be a repost to me.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Personally, I think you should have posted that as an answer for this. It's all too well explained for being a simple comment. This IMHO.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - Done :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you set `0007` as permission, it means that neither the owner or the group will be able to access the file/folder, while everyone else can. That's the opposite of what you want.

When using `chmod` in PHP, the permissions are (from left to right):

- First zero = defining the value as an octal value.
- Second number = the owners permission.
- Third number = The groups permission.
- Fourth number = Everyone else's permission.

You can read up on that function by reading the manual on PHP.net:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - No worries. Anything that makes the answer better is welcome.