# How to create a directory with php and chmod it to 0777?

Tags: php, chmod

How to create a directory with php and chmod it to 0777? I have searched other stack articles related to chmod via PHP, all are file related, not directory...

```
public function store(Document $document) {

    if (!isset($document->id)) { $document->id = $this->generateId(); }

        //This is my guess how to do it..
        $this->path      = $this->path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        if (!file_exists($this->path)) {
            mkdir($this->path);
            chmod($this->path, 0777);
        }
    //My guess does not work

    $path    = $this->getPathForDocument($document->id);
    $data    = $this->formatter->encode((array) $document);

    return file_put_contents($path, $data);
}
```

Comment: `mkdir($this->path, 0777);`, which is the default. What's your real problem? What's not working?

Comment: I don't think you need the `chmod($this->path, 0777);` because mkdir has default 2nd parameter with `0777` i.e The mode is 0777 by default, which means the widest possible access. We can change it. But in your case no need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure that your current web server user has write permissions on that folder where you want to run the mkdir command. If not, you can’t use PHP‘s mkdir method. If you can’t create a folder you can also not change it’s ownership.

Therefore, first make sure that your Webserver user has appropriate permissions. Then run your code above.

Comment: It would be helpful for visitors if you also elaborate on how to find out web server user and directory permissions.

Comment: "What's not working?" If there is no folder in the directory it does not create one. If there is no folder it cannot write the file. ..elaborate on how to find out web server user and directory permissions." Agreed. When i chmod the directory with WinSCP it says on new form .json file creation that the owner is www-data which is nothing that is part of any file in the system i can see. Everything else is marked as owner root.

Comment: @dogano how do I "ensure that your current web server user has write permissions on that folder"?

Comment: @Federkun "What's not working?" If there is no folder in the directory it does not create one. If there is no folder it cannot write the file

Comment: @AhmedNumaan I was thinking this exactly... how to find out web server user and directory permissions?

Comment: @WerewolF There is this tutorial which will help you understand file and directory permissions:
http://catcode.com/teachmod/index.html

Comment: @WerewolF have a look here: http://php.net/manual/de/function.is-writable.php

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled on this: [PHP mkdir: Permission denied problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246114/php-mkdir-permission-denied-problem)

They suggested this:
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/example.com/public_html/
chmod -R g+rw /var/www/example.com/public_html/

It actually worked.

Thanks :)