# Changing Apache/PHPs default file permissions

Tags: php, apache, file-permissions, umask

I have an Amazon EC2 server running Redhat. When my PHP CMS creates files they are owned by www-user and has chmod 644. How can I make all files created by Apache and PHP default to 666?

I've already tried adding "umask 002" in /etc/init.d/httpd but it doesn't seem to work.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've read that it depends on the parent folder rights.
Try to changed the rights on the parent folder to your apache user

What also may help:
[Apache permissions, PHP file create, MKDir fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165183/apache-permissions-php-file-create-mkdir-fail)