# Avoiding apache to run as root

Tags: php, apache, file-permissions

I am working on Apache server on localhost in Linux mint and need to create new file and folder using php script. But it is returning permission denied on 'mkdir' function.

I googled and found that Apache needs to run as root for such permissions. It is running as 'www-data' in my machine. But I also found that running Apache as root will open many vulnerabilities and there is no situation where Apache is needed to run as root.

How to overcome permission restrictions in apache?

Comment: Whoever told you / posted you should run apache as root is an idiot. Simply make sure that the permissions of the `www-data` user are set correctly

Comment: How to set permissions for www-data?

Comment: Please check with the permissions.

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 be nice.. - Apache does not need "root" for such permissions. you just need to have the perms for the folders correct.

Comment: @sircapsalot Are you sure you just read my comment correctly?

Comment: Where are you trying to create the directory, may be that path requires root privileges

Comment: @ShashwatKumar `chmod` / `chown` it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165183/apache-permissions-php-file-create-mkdir-fail

Comment: Worked. Changed the user and group of folders to www-data. Thanks to all for help.

Comment: There occurs a new problem. I changed the user and group of folders but not I am not able to edit the files since my user account is not www-data. How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NEVER EVER let apache run as root - in case of any flaws in your PHP, consequences would be TERRIFYING

Also adding www-data to sudoers is like one of the worst ideas I've seen so far

You need root priviliges to MANAGE apache (start/stop etc)

Make sure that the folder in which you have the PHP script belongs to www-data user & group, and it has sufficient permissions. Also, I don't know how your PHP is configured, but if you are using PHP as CGI, make sure that PHP is also running as www-data

`system('whoami');`

will help you to determine the user :)